# how to get data for a crypto on coinmarketcap api when there is multiple crypto with the same name

Tags: cryptocurrency, coinmarketcap

i'm trying to get the data for a crypto named Jade protocol but when i call jade in my search it give me the data for Jade currency.

i'm using a simple call:
https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?symbol=BTC,JADE,CRO,TIME

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use only ID or at least slugs in queries to avoid such problems.
The slug can be found in the URL of the coin (coinmarketcap.com/currencies/**jade-protocol**/), but it is better to call [CoinMarketCap ID Map](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyMap) and find there the ID or slug by the name of the coin (in case the slug ever changes).